# how to replace a part of statement between specific words without changing the rest of the statement in a file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

For eg, the statement is as follows :

```
Student named John has 23 apples. Docter says, apples are good for health.
```

I want to replace the string between `named` and `apples` with `Conor has 10`

After executing the shell script, the string should be like as follows :

**Desired result :**

```
Student named Conor has 10 apples. Docter says, apples are good for health.
```

For this I used the following sed command in a shell script:

```bash
file="input.txt"
new_text1="Conor has 10"
sed -i "s/named.*apples/named $new_text1 apples/g" "$file"
```

However, the output after executing this is as follows :

```
Student named Conor has 10 apples that are good for health.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to describe this transformation by _replace John by Conor_?

Comment: will the input always include a period after `apples` (or whatever the ending string may be)?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the `.` after `apples` too, otherwise the greedy regex will match up until the second occurrence of `apples` in the second string:

```bash
$ sed -i "s/named.*apples\./named $new_text1 apples\./g" "$file"
$ cat "$file"
Student named Conor has 10 apples. Docter says, apples are good for health.
```

Comment: Thanks Paolo. but Is there any other way ?

Comment: @Discovery yes, but why do you ask? what's wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do non-greedy matching, to get the shortest match for `named ... apples`.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, `sed` does not support non-greedy match. One alternative is to use *perl* instead of *sed*:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/named.*?apples/named $new_text1 apples/g" "$file"
```

Comment: Have you tested the code? I'm afraid `sed` regex (ERE) does not support the non-greedy match.

Comment: @thiono: I thought they are part of ERE. Will try to fix this.

Comment: The non-greedy match is supported by PCRE.

Comment: @tshiono : That's why I changed my answer from sed to perl now. Could you plese check whether it looks reasonable? My test worked well.

Comment: It works perfect! Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ei.bak "s/(named )[^.]*( apples)/\1${new_text1}\2/" input_file
Student named Conor has 10 apples. Docter says, apples are good for health.
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to match the first `apples` but `sed` is greedy and matches the second, instead. If you could specify that `.*` shall not match `apples` things would be much easier. You can do that if you first replace the first `apples` by a single character that cannot be found elsewhere in the same line, say a newline.

Example with any `sed` (output prefixed with `-|`):

```
sed "s/apples/\n/;s/named.*\n/named $new_text1 apples/" "$file"
-| Student named Conor has 10 apples. Docter says, apples are good for health.
```

Note that if a line contains `apples` but is not matching `named.*apples`, `apples` is replaced by a newline and not restored. If this can happen you can use:

```
sed "/named.*apples/s/apples/\n/;s/named.*\n/named $new_text1 apples/" "$file"
```

A bit more generic:

```
pre="named"; post="apples"; repl="Conor has 10 "; file="input.txt"
sed "/$pre.*$post/s/$post/\n/;s/$pre.*\n/$repl$post/" "$file"
-| Student Conor has 10 apples. Docter says, apples are good for health.
```

Note that the replacement text now contains a final space. Note also that the `pre` and `post` text strings shall not contain characters that would be interpreted as regex operators (periods, stars...) and `repl` shall not contain replacement operators (ampersands...). If they do they must be escaped (`post="apples\."`).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/apples/\n/;s/named[^\n]*\n/named Connor has 10 apples/;/\n/g' file
```

Make a copy of the line.

Replace the first occurrence of `apples` by a newline. A newline cannot be present in any line presented by sed as that is the way sed delimits each line (unless the `-z` option is in uses).

Replace the string `named[^\n]*\n` and replace by required string. That is the string `named` followed by any character other than a newline (zero or more times) followed by a newline.

If the substitution has failed a newline will still be present in the line, thus replace the ameliorated line by the original copy.

This assumes the word `apples` does not occur before `named`. A more robust solution would be:

```
sed -E ':a;s/(named.*)apples/\1\n/;ta;s/\n/apples/2g
        s/named.*\n/named Connor has 10 apples/' file
```

This works backwards through the line replacing `apples` by newlines after the word `named`. Then replaces all but the first newline with `apples` and then replaces the string `named` thru newline with the required string.